# Как подружить постгрес и денвер

Tags: php, denwer

Денвер - версия 3, PHP Version 5.3.13. Версия постгресс - 9.3.3. Ругается на базовое pg_connect() как понял нужен какой то php_pgsql.dll. Офф ссылки не нашел, есть какие то вири (нет доверия), на стэке написали

```
On a Windows server, configured with Apache, adding the following line to httpd.conf to load libpq.dll can save you a lot of time :

LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/libpq.dll"
```

Пруф - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551734/php-not-loading-php-pgsql-dll-on-windows

Постгрес стоит на линукс-серваке, то есть путь не подходит. 
еще слышал в пхп.ини нужно что то раскоментировать но хз что.  В общем в пхп новичек, кто сталкивался подскакжите.

Ой зачем я суда вообще пишу, все равно сам разбираюсь быстрее. Дело было в следующем - для денвера нужно установить допкомпоненты. 
пруф http://www.denwer.ru/packages/postgresql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под разные версии PHP будут разные версии php_pgsql.dll. Выясните, какая версия PHP используется у вас, найдите на [оф. сайте](http://windows.php.net/download) сборку этой версии под Windows и возьмите оттуда эту dll, либо скачайте последнюю сборку и замените весь PHP в Денвере.

В php.ini как раз эту библиотеку и надо раскомментировать (при наличии dll файла)